# Shape.Height and Shape.Width problems in PowerPoint 2013

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-2013

I am using a small VBA script to apply some text in the background. The script works fine on PowerPoint 2007 and PowerPoint 2010.

However, in PowerPoint 2013, setting Shape.Height and Shape.Width has no effect.  Here is the snippet of the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub applyWatermark()

Dim curDesign As Design
Set curDesign = ActivePresentation.Designs.Item(1)
Dim masterSlide As Master
Set masterSlide = curDesign.SlideMaster

Dim shape As shape
Set shape = masterSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoShapeRectangle, 0#, 0#, 100#, 100#)

shape.TextEffect.Text = "Watermark"

' Setting height and width works fine on PPT 2010 but does not work on PPT 2013
shape.Height = 200
shape.Width = 300

shape.TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoTrue
shape.TextFrame2.WarpFormat = msoWarpFormat1
shape.Left = 200
shape.Top = 200

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the height & width properties in the `Set shape = masterSlide.Shapes...` ??  Perhaps that will be more reliable.

Comment: I posted this question on msdn and got a workaround to set warpFormat to msoWarpForm37 and that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with PowerPoint 2013.

Workaround is to set

```
Myshape.TextFrame2.WarpFormat = msoWarpFormat37
```

Workaround is provided at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/2c1cf339-aa90-4d82-9475-0ff5f49ac1b1/.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a known limitation to the MS development team - in some instances it just doesn't fire correctly. One suggestion is to change the font size instead, but that doesn't help much if you actually need a specific font size in the shape.

Comment: Indeed. `.height` (and width, top and left for that matter) are the only places where I consistently get this sort of error, they simply won't fire unless you step through using F8. I've had this on TextBoxes, ChartObject.PlotArea, etc... If I recall correctly, in most cases if you `Select` the shape, it will set these properties correctly.  I hate `Select` since it can usually be avoided, but this is the one place I think I have needed to use it.

Comment: Select is a suitable workaround - I hadn't even thought of that.